# Jquery/Javascript?? & video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I can't find what I'm looking for. I think mainly because, I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I have this script running. It's working, I'm hosting the script on my Server2012r2 box, the video is hosted on my Google.Drive account.

How do I code this page to a variable for adding more video? I know there is a way, this page can be coded to load variable content. So I don't have to write a new HTML page for every video.... I've been trying to google but I'm very confused. If anyone can point me towards a tutorial or the proper term I'm looking for so I can get some accurate info. I understand a small bit, how Jquery does this. I have found a few examples of the page scrip for the player. I'm not sure where to go from there. What info needs to be in the link to the player, so the player knows which video to play?

Thank you...

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sports</Title>
    <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<style>

Header {
    height: 50px; width 800px;
    background-image: url("HeaderBg.png");
    Background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-Position: Center top;
    Margin-top: 3px;
}

H1 { text-align: center; }

nav {
    float: right; 
    Padding-right: 4%;
    Height: 300px; Width: 213px;
    Background-image: url("navbg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

P { text-align: center; }

body {
    background-image: url("grade.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>

<body bgcolor=#D3D3D3 link=white vlink=white alink=black>

    <Header>
        <H1><font size="10" face="Courier New" Color="White">Dust To Glory</font><H1>
    </Header>

    <br><br><br><br>

    <nav>
        <p>
            <a href="https://1bba518163fe958be7ef0564758db2cc8352ecf4.googledrive.com/host/0B2pNuTLUXBp_fjJPRkFYVDQ4MG1VWVByckdqbVdrbWdIejR3WXU5WTZBZThtZHhwbHQ4RzQ/dtg.mp4" download><font size="6">Download</a>
        </p>
    </nav>

    <Center>
        <video width="60%" height="60%" controls>
            <source src="https://1bba518163fe958be7ef0564758db2cc8352ecf4.googledrive.com/host/0B2pNuTLUXBp_fjJPRkFYVDQ4MG1VWVByckdqbVdrbWdIejR3WXU5WTZBZThtZHhwbHQ4RzQ/dtg.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>

            <source src="https://1bba518163fe958be7ef0564758db2cc8352ecf4.googledrive.com/host/0B2pNuTLUXBp_fjJPRkFYVDQ4MG1VWVByckdqbVdrbWdIejR3WXU5WTZBZThtZHhwbHQ4RzQ/dtg.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>

            <source src="https://1bba518163fe958be7ef0564758db2cc8352ecf4.googledrive.com/host/0B2pNuTLUXBp_fjJPRkFYVDQ4MG1VWVByckdqbVdrbWdIejR3WXU5WTZBZThtZHhwbHQ4RzQ/dtg.webm" type="video/webm"/>
        </video>
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try URL encoding

pass in the URL of the video as a URL encoded variable

( http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp )

This required that you know the url of which video you want to load.

you can then read the url and parse the variable and set the src of the video to the URL from the encoded URL. Thus, with the same page you can load many videos so long as you know their proper URL

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know how you created the webpage in the first place.

if you can run php you might try writing a switch case statement that just puts the right link on the page?

`
<?php
if (link 1)
echo <video src = link1>;
...
?>  `

Comment: sorry for the mess of a comment. 

first comment in this forum. still figuring stuff out